# Логирование время выполнения kernel events в Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Бывают аномалии на проде в виде долгих запросов. Нужно узнать на каком этапе происходят эти аномалии. Для этого я создал Listeners для каждого kernel events (request, controller, response и т.д). Сделал debug логирование. Но не могу понять/найти как узнать/рассчитать время выполнения данного события.

Есть ограничение, решить это надо путем самого Symfony + php, без установки каких то пакетов и расширений.

[image: Пример слушателя kernel.request]

Comment: Из коробки у symfony дебарег идёт, там в панели всё красиво нарисовано, весь путь запроса.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev Я в курсе, но его нельзя использовать на проде( много уязвимостей ). А локально этих аномалий нет. Поэтому командой было принято решение добавить логирование что бы посмотреть логи на проде.

Comment: На 100% не уверен, но там можно по ip дебагер вывести. По крайней мере, я помню, что раньше так делал.

Comment: Поставьте Blackfire триальный и не придется изобретать какие то костыли.

Answer (score 0):

Решил через StopWatch. В эвенте "а" начинал и в эвенте "b" заканчивал и логировал.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]